# Android UICC SIM

Tags: android, euiccmanager, uicc

New to the group and have a question.

Working on a solution where we have a UICC SIM in an andriod handset. Looking at sending the SIM profile to the device to program the plastic SIM with a new profile. Obviously the feature exists for eSIM but I have a specific requirement for plastic SIM (UICC to avoid confusion).

1. Can this be done?
2. If not has anyone developed a piece of code that can do this?

Not tried anything yet. Have been told by another party that asked Google that it might need some development

Comment: So you want to send remote APDUs to the SIM card? As this can only be done by the SIM card owner (thus the network operator) the number of developers who com in contact with such a solution is pretty low. I also only know a bit if theory, but shouldn't this work independently of the Smartphone OS?

Comment: So the card is eUICC compliant and sat in an Android handset. As with eSIM, I want to to be able to send the profile to the eUICC plastic SIM - the same way as an eSIM would be uploaded.

Comment: That require special SIM cards that act like a eSIM, something like https://esim.me . But I think those cards use a proprietary API. Regular SIM cards are locked by the vendor (the network operator). You can not use regular SIM cards besides the common functions PIN/PUK, address book, SIM toolkit functions.